# How to clear history on logout

Tags: bash, history

I tried adding `history -c` to `~/.bash_logout` but seems not working.

---

**Add:**

I'm having success by adding these lines into my `~/.bashrc` (referred from [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/clear-the-shell-history-in-ubuntu-linux/))

```
unset HISTFILE
export LESSHISTFILE=/dev/null
```

I still don't know why `history -c` method won't work.

Comment: history of what?! bash or all shells or the whole system please be more specific so edit your question to be so

Comment: @maythux history of my bash shell commands that I typed. From SSH to be specific. History of whole system = history for all users?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many history settings available via the builtin command `set -o` or environment variables, see [bash's documentation on its history facilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Facilities).  From that, it follows that `HISTFILE=/dev/null` will let bash save the history into the void.

Comment: I also sometimes use `kill -9 $$` which means less typing, but is not nice.  $$ is the current process, i.e. the shell itself, and the forceful kill prevents it from writing to `$HISTFILE`, too.  However, it also prevents it from doing other cleanups, and setting `HISTFILE=/dev/null` can be done much earlier (before leaving the shell), so one cannot accidentally quit the shell the wrong way. Plus, any intermediate history saving would also go to /dev/null.

Comment: Args, long docs. But anyhow I'm having success with your solution!

Comment: The environment variables are cleared after logout? Must it be done everytime?

Comment: Yes, all environment variables are cleared after logout. Basically, the whole environment's lifetime ends with the logout.

Answer (score 1):

This will only work, if you are in a **login** shell and leave it by

- `exit` or
- `logout` or
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.

If you simply close a Gnome Terminal, `~/bash_logout` is not executed.

Comment: I use SSH with Putty. I did use both `exit` and close the ssh client straight away, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

history -c will be available by default, you Don't have to add it , if need to remove every history try this , echo " " > ~/.bash_history

Comment: Without `history -c`, my history just accumulates with thousands of history lines.